# ListView for buttons using BaseAdapters

Tags: android

i am trying to perform some actions on the  click of the button from the ListView .
OnClickListener dosent get called on the click of the button.

Here is my
MainActivity.java

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final ListView myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        final Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        //create the adapter
        final rowNumAdapter rownumadapter = new rowNumAdapter(this);
        myListView.setAdapter(rownumadapter);
        myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {


                if(position==0)
                {
                     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You just clicked"+ rownumadapter.getItem(position) , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

            }
        });
        myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

                rownumadapter.addrows();

            }
        });
}
```

}

Here is my
rowNumAdapter.java

public class rowNumAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
private Context mContext;
private  int numrows;


public rowNumAdapter(Context context) {

    this.mContext=context;
    this.numrows= 5;

}
public void addrows()
{
    this.numrows+=1;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return this.numrows;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {

    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {

    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

     Button view = null;
    if(convertView == null)
    {   
        view = new Button(this.mContext);
    }
    else
    {
        view = (Button)convertView;
    }

    view.setText(" row " + position);


    return view;
}
```

}

Here is my 
activity_main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="15dp">

<Button
android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:text="Add View"
android:id="@+id/button"></Button>

<ListView
android:id="@+id/listView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:focusable="false"
android:clickable="false"
 >

</ListView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `getView`  method from your adapter class. [Ref](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29).

It should be something like this.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) thisContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View vi = convertView;

    // your layout will be here
    vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);

    // Set your button id here 
    Button btnCheckin = (Button) vi.findViewById(R.id.btnCheckIn);

        btnCheckin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                    Log.d("you clicked", "the item at [" + position
                            + "] position");
                   // your button action here.

            }
        });
    } 

    return vi;
}
```

[Here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#tutorial_ownadapter) is a good tutorial about `ListView` and `adapters`.